# How do I reshape my existing JSON to fit Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, highcharts

I am new to JS and I am having trouble with feeding my data to Highcharts for visualization.

Say I have a following JSON data

```
{  
   "is_error":0,
   "keys":[  
      "count",
      "created_date",
      "source",
      "gender_id",
      "type"
   ],
   "error":"",
   "values":[  
      {  
         "count":3,
         "created_date":"2017-08-09",
         "source":"",
         "gender_id":"",
         "type":"Organization"
      },
      {  
         "count":1,
         "created_date":"2017-08-10",
         "source":"",
         "gender_id":"",
         "type":"Organization"
      },
      {  
         "count":2,
         "created_date":"2017-08-09",
         "source":"",
         "gender_id":1,
         "type":"Individual"
      },
      {  
         "count":1,
         "created_date":"2017-08-12",
         "source":"",
         "gender_id":1,
         "type":"Individual"
      }
   ]
}
```

How would I transform it to a Highcharts series array so that it looks something like this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Organization',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2017, 08, 09), 3],
        [Date.UTC(2017, 08, 10), 1],
    ]
}, {
    name: 'Individual',
    data: [
       [Date.UTC(2017, 08, 09), 2],
       [Date.UTC(2017, 08, 12), 1],
    ]
}]
```

In the JSON I have some information which isn't required (source and gender_id).

Here is my [example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kq06hmy6/) with full big data set that I want to transform using JS and fit it into a Highchart.

Is there an easy way to do transform a JSON like this to something which can be plugged into a Highchart?

Comment: Where does the second date come from in series.data ?

Comment: Individuals and Organizations both have only two data points, each datapoint is defined by one date and one number (count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kq06hmy6/2/) and update according to your needs

```
    series: chartData
```

Comment: Thanks. There is just a problem with dates and I can't seem to figure out why are day displayed the way they are on the x axis of the Highchart

Comment: Ok I got it `new Date(d.created_date).getTime()` needs to be used insted of `new Date(d.created_date)`. I added the change to [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kq06hmy6/3/)